# Emulator does not display localised simplified chinese text in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, cjk

Although I have created a resource file for simplified chinese AppResources.zh-CH.resx, and i have added it in the supported culture in the csproj, the chinese text is not displayed. Instead the default english text is shown when i change the language to simplified chinese.

Though those text such as the month name which is obtained from the WP OS is shown in chinese.

The other languages such as spanish and german works like a charm. I have created the generic german and spanish( AppResources.de.resx, and AppResources.es.resx)

Am i missing? Do i have to make changes for any other changes for chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entering the wrong (unsupported) culture for in the supported culture.
[Please check the following link for the supported language and culture.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202918%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)